# convert items within a tuple/list

Tags: python, list

I have the following list

```
[(199L, 5L, 247L, 44L), (203L, 5L, 245L, 6L), 
(219L, 5L, 196L, 6L)]
```

I use list.extend to add `[222L, 5L, 227L, 5L]` to it but the list now becomes

```
[(199L, 5L, 247L, 44L), (203L, 5L, 245L, 6L), 
(219L, 5L, 196L, 6L), 222L, 5L, 227L, 5L ]
```

However I would like it to be in the format..

```
[(199L, 5L, 247L, 44L), (203L, 5L, 245L, 6L), 
(219L, 5L, 196L, 6L), (222L, 5L, 227L, 5L)]
```

Would anyone know how to do that..?

Comment: Use `list.append` - not `list.extend` - look at the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) for the difference... Also check out [effbot's reference](http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm)

Comment: You don't need to use `L` after every integer to make it a `long`, Python 2.7 `int`s will be promoted to `long` when necessary

Comment: Above list assignment is giving me invalid syntax error. Do I need to import some package for 'L'?

Comment: I guess it's because I am using python 3 and above. And 'l' or 'L' are from previous to python 3 versions

Comment: @Drt Yes in python 3 there is no distinction between `int` and `long`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `list.append()`.

```
>>> lis = [(199L, 5L, 247L, 44L), (203L, 5L, 245L, 6L), 
... (219L, 5L, 196L, 6L)]
>>> lis.append((222L, 5L, 227L, 5L))
>>> lis
[(199L, 5L, 247L, 44L), (203L, 5L, 245L, 6L), (219L, 5L, 196L, 6L), (222L, 5L, 227L, 5L)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> lst = [(199L, 5L, 247L, 44L), (203L, 5L, 245L, 6L), (219L, 5L, 196L, 6L)]
>>> lst.append((222L, 5L, 227L, 5L))
```